# How can I specify which GPU to use when using Huggingface Trainer

Tags: huggingface-transformers

HuggingFace offers training_args like below. When I use HF trainer to train my model, I found cuda:0 is used by default.

I went through the HuggingFace Docs, but still don't know how to specify which GPU to run on when using HF trainer.

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,              # total # of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common and practical way to control which GPU to use is to set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable.

If you want to use this option in the command line when running a python script, you can do it like this:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python train.py
```

Alternatively, you can insert this code before the import of PyTorch or any other CUDA-based library (like HuggingFace Transformers):

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"  # or "0,1" for multiple GPUs
```

This way, regardless of how many GPUs you have on your machine, the Hugging Face Trainer will only be able to see and use the GPU(s) that you have specified.